Getting 500 error when using Kony SDK with HCL Foundry via .NET
I am calling a service from my login controller and passing the username and password as part of the Authorization header. Below is the code that is responsible for calling the login service.
     public async Task<ApiResponse> UserLoginV2(HttpRequest request)
     {

         _logger.LogInformation($"Starting {nameof(UserLoginV2)}");

         if (!request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out var authHeader))
         {
             return JsonHelper.ParseError("Auth header is missing");
         }

         var header = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(authHeader);
         var credentials = header.Parameter;

         try
         {
             var decodedCredential = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(credentials));
             var credentialParts = decodedCredential.Split(':');

             if (credentialParts.Length != 2)
             {
                 _logger.LogWarning("Invalid credential format.");
                 return JsonHelper.ParseError("Invalid credential format", null, HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
             }

             string username = credentialParts[0];
             string password = credentialParts[1];

             if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
             {
                 _logger.LogWarning("Username or password is empty.");
                 return JsonHelper.ParseError("Invalid credentials", null, HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
             }

             if (failedLoginAttempts.ContainsKey(username) && failedLoginAttempts[username] >= MaxFailedAttempts)
             {
                 _logger.LogWarning($"User {username} is locked out due to too many failed login attempts.");
                 return JsonHelper.ParseError("Account locked due to too many failed login attempts", null, HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
             }

             HeaderHelper headerHelper = new HeaderHelper();
             Dictionary<string, string> headers = headerHelper.GenerateHeaders(username, password);
             Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
             {
                 { "apiVersion", "19.123.7" },
                 { "grant_type", "password" },
                 { "realm", "webcustomer" }
             };

             JObject result = await _koniConsumeService.GetInvokeServiceOperationAsync(_serviceName, "UserLoginV2", headers, parameters);
             if (result != null)
             {

                 if (result.ContainsKey("message") && (string)result["message"] == "Unauthorized access.")
                 {
                     _logger.LogWarning($"Unauthorized access for user {username}.");
                     return JsonHelper.ParseError("Unauthorized access", "Invalid Username/Password", HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                 }

                 var clientId = (string)result["client_id"];
                 var foundryApiToken = (string)result["access_token"];

                 List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
                     {
                         new Claim("client_id", clientId),
                         new Claim("foundry_apis_token", foundryApiToken)
                     };

                 _logger.LogInformation($"Successful login for user {username}.");
                 return JsonHelper.ParseSuccess(GenerateJSONWebToken(claims));
             }

             _logger.LogWarning($"Authentication failed for user {username}.");
             return JsonHelper.ParseError("Authentication failed", null, HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);

         }
         catch (FormatException)
         {
             _logger.LogError("Error decoding the Authorization header.");
             return JsonHelper.ParseError("UnAuthorized", null, HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
         }
         finally
         {
             _logger.LogInformation($"End {nameof(UserLoginV2)}");
         }

     }

I have downloaded the Kony DLL and added it to my project. The service call looks like this:
    public async Task<JObject> GetInvokeServiceOperationAsync(string serviceName, string operationName, Dictionary<string, string> headers, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
    {
        JObject result = null;
        IntegrationService integrationSvc = null;
        try
        {
            integrationSvc = sdkObject.GetIntegrationService(serviceName);
            _logger.LogInformation($"Calling Service : {serviceName} Operation : {operationName}");

            result = await integrationSvc.InvokeOperationAsync(operationName, headers, parameters);

            _logger.LogInformation($"End Calling Service Operation");
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException e) when (e.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("Unauthorized access to the API.");
            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("Unauthorized access", e);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (integrationSvc == null)
            {
                _logger.LogError("Invalid Service");
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.LogError("Invoke operation failed"); 
            }
            throw;
        }

        return result;
    }
}

Here is my HeaderHelper class that adds headers to the request:

        public Dictionary<string, string> GenerateHeaders(string username, string password)
        {
            string encodedCredentials =
                Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password));

            Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "X-Ibm-Client-Id", "4686c049-1e93-4eb2-8127-dfbce48aaa56" },
                { "Accept", "application/json" },
                { "Accept-Language", "en-gb" },
                { "Authorization",  encodedCredentials },
                //{ "Cache-Control", "no-cache" },
                { "Connection", "keep-alive" },
                { "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
                { "Deviceinfo", "eyJDaGFubmVsIjoid2ViIiwib3NWZXJzaW9uIjoid2luZG93cy0xMCIsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiIiwidXNlckRldmljZUlQIjoiIiwiZGV2aWNlIjoiV2luZG93cyIsIkRldmljZV9JRCI6IiIsIlRpbWVzdGFtcCI6IjIwMjMtMDctMjBUMTA6Mzk6MDMuOTU1WiJ9" },
                {"Channel", "web"},
                {"Response", "03AAYGu2SUlqt1e_kzVtBKGl1uZ-6n0z0d69vQECf_wgGRuQAyz7Yito0Kbywd5YRAy92gagN-gRKhcm-wDXN1ShouxQKmVr7aHREkikiox7AaT3RW-dte8gIuTidPUbQ1Ri1R49w8UI9G7R_A4HfYMRy6jZEobmIpVAXfrNGfQAmR85mWi8Pw_p18IEwJaMKbbi9PgsDRikHMcYQQi9d7hwxUkepREbIHSaurIThLhQnkSgHioUPU7vhv_oEjk74WVE1OajoHr52qgOmYxRLYRF2SAJGbRcqEAgl52Gh6nju3Ht3PBhhQmJUtu47IRkDgaWXwsaKRi43iVYEnmq4n9pPiO2Vw02sIRmpaV6VrBLA9gxwugcHblgTp63gHg5Qhd3RBOZjkhXkDY8-28jiusmYzCvMddhBEXvi9kSfN55u3VipvJohgtXLW_yCVbQ8niIsLeeR1Pffij6s_aCdSJJ2k7JJVtebnV8YwO208tD-Z_J3ufAnJKF6lbGWzRLA1CaZ2vvzIq6eo9V-KGOpqU562EBWOu8IgqM1J09qiTShEk59pZNlTR_bnwzX6hZje7ut1kykXw4Di"},
                {"language", "en"}
            };

            return headers;
        }

Regardless of the request, the Kony SDK is throwing a 500 error. When calling the HCL Foundry service via the console app, I’m also getting the same 500 error.
I've checked the headers and parameters, and everything seems to be in place. I have limited visibility into the root cause from the SDK’s side.
Question:
Has anyone faced similar issues with Kony SDK and HCL Foundry, and how did you resolve the 500 error?
Is there something I am missing when invoking the service via the Kony SDK in .NET?
Any guidance or advice is appreciated.
